# PHP - Introducir valores a variables de forma dinámica

Tags: php, html

Me estaba preguntando si es posible el siguiente proceso en PHP:

Un usuario ingresa lo siguiente a un **Input HTML**:

```
"ayudo personas con discapacidadAuditiva";
```

Se envía a PHP, para que una función la divida en secciones.

```
"ayudo" => $variable1 => "Comprobar si existe en el Array() Acciones."
"personas" => $variable2 => "Comprobar si existe en el Array() identificativos."
"con" => $variable3 => "Comprobar si existe en el Array() preparadores."
"discapacidadAuditiva" => $variable4 => "Comprobar si existe en el Array() categoriasIdentificativos."
```

Array() Acciones:

```
["ayudo","expulso","educo"]
```

Array() Identificativos:

```
["personas","estudiantes","indigentes"]
```

Array() Preparadores:

```
["con","de"]
```

Array() CategoriasIdentificativos:

```
["discapacidadAuditiva","hambre","tareas"]
```

---

### Como si PHP leyera el string del **Input HTML** de la siguiente forma:

```
"$variable1 $variable2 $variable3 $variable4"
```

Y si se encuentran las variables en sus Array() respectivamente, la función devuelva true.

Es esto posible? Si es así, como podría realizarlo.

Hasta el momento lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>❤</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jq3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jq-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
<form class="loader" method="POST" action="procesar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="data">
    <button type="submit">Cargar datos</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**procesar.php**

```
<?php
$string = $_POST['data'];
function comprobaciones($string){
    //Now what? :(
}
?>
```

> He intentado usar RegExp:

```
$preg = "/^(\w*)\s+(\w*)\s+(\w*)\s+(\w*)$/i";
function pregnated($preg,$grupo,$fuente){
    $grupo = "$".$grupo;
    return preg_replace($preg, $grupo, $fuente);
}
$accion = pregnated($preg,1,$string);
$identificativo = pregnated($preg,2,$string);
$preparador = pregnated($preg,3,$string);
$categoriaIdentificativo = pregnated($preg,4,$string);
```

Pero pues, no se si esta sea la mejor forma :/

Comment: No me queda claro si siempre `accion identificador prep cat`... ¿Qué debería suceder si alguien escribe `a mí me gusta ayudar...`? Si puede ocurrir este último ejemplo, quizás te interese investigar sobre [NLP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procesamiento_de_lenguajes_naturales)... Es un tema que no se resuelve tan fácil

Comment: Pues, al no encontrarse el valor en el Array() correspondiente arroja false, entonces la comprobacion arroja un error.

Comment: sigo sin entender. La frase debería ser **exactamente** igual y en ese orden?

Comment: Si, segun los contenidos de los Array(). :)))))))))))))))))))

Comment: _Y si se encuentran las variables en sus **Array()** respectivamente, la funcion devuelva true._ Tenemos pues una cadena que viene de un input, hasta ahí he entendido. Pero me perdí cuando hablas de _sus Array()_ ¿? ¿Qué arrays son esos que no los veo?

Comment: Voy a tener que editar.

Comment: No veo el porque sea necesario que incluya los Array()...

Comment: Tienes que incluirlos porque no estamos dentro de tu mente para intuir  lo que quieres hacer. No es simple curiosidad de saber lo que escondes en tus array sino deseo de entender lo que quieres hacer. Ya queda más claro. Aunque hay todavía​ algo que no entiendo. **Casi** se trataría en el primer paso de evaluar **cada palabra** de la cadena. Pero me pierdo  de nuevo cuando en el ejemplo evalúas juntas **las dos últimas** palabras. ¿Es ese el patrón de comportamiento ? ¿Evaluar cada palabra por separado excepto las dos últimas ?

Comment: Si, asi es. Aunque si solo se puede con una palabra. Igual daria con mi situacion :)

Comment: Re-edited.......

Comment: @MáximaAlekz Recuerda que en tu caso, puedes ingresar al chat, e incluso podrias crear una sala, para discutir bien tu inconveniente y lo que deseas obtener

Comment: @MáximaAlekz Aunque bien, acabo de agregar mi respuesta, segun lo que te he entendido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Antes de empezar

El acceso a los elementos de los arreglos superglobales *(POST, GET)* de una manera directa no esta recomendado en PHP.

*Por lo tanto:*

Lo primero que te recomiendo es que sustituyas el valor de esta variable:

```
$string = $_POST['data'];
```

Por:

```
$string = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "data", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

#### ¿Que hicimos aquí?

Cambiamos la forma de acceder a los datos recibidos vía *POST*, usando la función [filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php) de PHP, a esta función le indicamos:

- Origen de las variables (INPUT_POST)
- Nombre de la variable
- Bandera, esta se usa para "limpiar" los valores que recibirás del formulario.

Esto nos sirve para "limpiar" los datos recibidos del navegador, se suele usar como una medida de seguridad.

### Empecemos!

De acuerdo a lo que entiendo de tu pregunta, ***lo que quieres es que PHP pueda "extraer" cada una de las palabras que ingresas, de modo que las organice en distintos arreglos.***

> Nota: En este ejemplo que haré, lo haré con una cadena escrita por mi, y lo único que haría falta es reemplazarla por la variable que llega del *POST*.

#### Primero

He creado 4 (cuatro) arreglos, en los que se guardaran cada una de las palabras que extraeremos (basado en tu pregunta):

```
$acciones        = array();
$identificativos = array();
$preparadores    = array();
$categorias      = array();
```

La función `comprobaciones` tal como tu la has creado, la he dejado de esta manera:

```
function comprobaciones($informacion, &$acciones, &$identificativos, &$preparadores, &$categorias)
```

**¿Que quiere decir esto?**

A la función `comprobaciones` le pasaremos como argumentos:

1. Variable contenedora del texto
2. Arreglo de Acciones (por referencia)
3. Arreglo de Identificativos (por referencia)
4. Arreglo de Preparadores (por referencia)
5. Arreglo de Categorias (por referencia)

Los arreglos se pasan por referencia, ¿porque?, por que es muy posible que los uses después, en otra parte de tu código, o bien, por el simple hecho, que como buena practica de programación, es bueno que el cuerpo de las funciones no sea muy grande, ya que esto haría mas tediosas las cosas cuando se tengan que modificar *(cohesión y coherencia)* :)

### Segundo

La función `comprobaciones` contendrá los siguientes arreglos:

```
$textoAccion          = array("ayudar", "alimentar", "comer", "salir");
$textoIdentificativos = array("persona", "estudiante", "habitante");
$textoPreparadores    = array("con", "de", "a");
$textoCategorias      = array("hambre", "tareas", "juego", "alimento");
```

Pero, ***¿Para que nos sirven estos arreglos?***

En estos arreglos tendremos las palabras que buscaremos en nuestro texto *(de acuerdo a tu ejemplo).*

***¿Cual es el problema?***

Si escribimos en el arreglo todas las posibles palabras que podemos buscar, los arreglos podrían contener cientos de elementos. Y también harían el código demasiado grande.

***¿Como se podría solucionar?***

Una posible solución, es que llenes los arreglos desde una base de datos, así todas las palabras posibles podrían ser ingresadas vía script, o vía teclado. Lo que haría el código, mas legible y mas dinámico.

### Tercero

Vamos a usar tres funciones embebidas en PHP:

- [trim()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php)
- [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtolower.php)
- [explode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)
- [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php)

trim(): Permite eliminar caracteres tanto al inicio, como al final de una cadena, lo usaremos para eliminar los espacios en blanco en cada palabra.

strtolower(): Convierte una palabra a minúsculas, ¿Porque?, para tener como una regla general, que todas la palabras posibles estarán en minúscula, es decir, si buscas **Hambre**, seria distinto a **hambre**, por tanto todas se buscaran en minúscula.

explode(): Permite separar las cadenas, basados en un "separador".

in_array(): Busca si un elemento se encuentra o no en un arreglo.

### Pasemos al código

Pero antes, una síntesis de lo que hice.

> Extraemos cada una de las palabras del texto, posteriormente, cada cadena sera limpiada de caracteres usando trim() y sera convertida a minúscula, posteriormente, cada palabra sera buscada en el arreglo de palabras posibles y en el arreglo de palabras ya extraídas, SI EXISTE EN EL ARREGLO DE PALABRAS BUSCADAS Y NO EXISTE EN EL ARREGLO DE PALABRAS YA EXTRAÍDAS, entonces se AGREGA.

Voilà el codigo:

```
<?php

$acciones        = array();
$identificativos = array();
$preparadores    = array();
$categorias      = array();

$informacion = "Me gusta alimentar a una persona con hambre y ayudarla en sus tareas para salir a jugar despues a la calle y ayudar a otro habitante";

comprobaciones($informacion, $acciones, $identificativos, $preparadores, $categorias);


print "Acciones: ";
var_dump($acciones);
print "\n";

print "Identificativos: ";
var_dump($identificativos);
print "\n";

print "Preparadores: ";
var_dump($preparadores);
print "\n";

print "Categorias: ";
var_dump($categorias);
print "\n";




function comprobaciones($informacion, &$acciones, &$identificativos, &$preparadores, &$categorias){

        /* Posibles textos*/
        $textoAccion          = array("ayudar", "alimentar", "comer", "salir");
        $textoIdentificativos = array("persona", "estudiante", "habitante");
        $textoPreparadores    = array("con", "de", "a");
        $textoCategorias      = array("hambre", "tareas", "juego", "alimento");

        foreach(explode(" ", $informacion) as $cadena){

                $cadena = trim(strtolower($cadena));


                // Buscamos -> Acciones
                if(in_array($cadena, $textoAccion) && !in_array($cadena, $acciones)){
                        $acciones[] = $cadena;
                }

                // Buscamos -> Identificativos
                if(in_array($cadena, $textoIdentificativos) && !in_array($cadena, $identificativos)){
                        $identificativos[] = $cadena;
                }

                // Buscamos -> Preparadores
                if(in_array($cadena, $textoPreparadores) && !in_array($cadena, $preparadores)){
                        $preparadores[] = $cadena;
                }

                // Buscamos -> Categorias
                if(in_array($cadena, $textoCategorias) && !in_array($cadena, $categorias)){
                        $categorias[] = $cadena;
                }

        }

}
```

Después de ejecutarlo, obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
Acciones: array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "alimentar"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "salir"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "ayudar"
}

Identificativos: array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "persona"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "habitante"
}

Preparadores: array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "con"
}

Categorias: array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "hambre"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "tareas"
}
```

Espero te ayude.

PD: Al usarlo con tu código actual, lo único que necesitas cambiar es:

```
$informacion = "Me gusta alimentar a una persona con hambre y ayudarla en sus tareas para salir a jugar despues a la calle y ayudar a otro habitante";
```

por:

```
$informacion = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "data", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: Antes que nada +1 por primera respuesta, buen material y explicaciones. Se acerca realmente a mi respuesta, aunque hay algunas cositas aun que no logro.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz Si tienes alguna duda, no dudes en contactarme, suelo pasar a menudo por el chat, y en mi perfil hay uno que otro medio de contacto, por si necesitas algo respecto al  codigo.

Comment: Esta bien, muchas gracias